# Swift - NSCoding archive does not work

Tags: ios, swift

I need to save object called Day.

```
class TimeSheet: NSObject, NSCoding{

static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("TimeSheet")

private static var days:[Day] = []


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    guard let days = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "days") as? [Day] else{
        os_log("No previous day data available.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return nil
    }
    TimeSheet.days = days
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder){
    aCoder.encode(TimeSheet.days, forKey: "days")
}

static func addDay(day: Day) -> Bool{
    TimeSheet.days.append(day)
    return TimeSheet.submitDay()
}

private static func submitDay() -> Bool{
    return NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(TimeSheet.days, toFile: TimeSheet.ArchiveURL.path)
}

static func loadDays(){
    guard let tempDays = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: TimeSheet.ArchiveURL.path) as? [Day] else{
        print("Could not loaded...")
        return
    }
    TimeSheet.days = tempDays
}
```

And I try to achieve from different class by:

```
@objc private func buttonPressed(button: UIButton!){
    if(TimeSheet.addDay(day: day)){
        print("Saved")
    }else{
        print("Not Saved")
    }
}
```

Everything works perfectly fine until save button is pressed and program hit **submitDay** function.
Terminal throws Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DayManager.Day encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000003391e0'

This is my first time using NSCoding and I cannot figure out what is going wrong...

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: What is DayManager? Does your Day class conform to NSCoding?

Comment: The error reveals that `Day` does not conform to `NSCoding`

Comment: That is the name of my project.

Comment: Oh I have my TimeSheet comfort but my Day does not comfort to NSCoding... okay I will try that

Comment: Is Day a class or a struct? It needs to conform to NSCoding, so it should be a class. Post your code for Day?

Comment: Any custom class which is going to be archived must conform to `NSCoding`

Comment: Thanks all. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your entire object graph to conform to NSCoding. That means that all the sub-objects that you try to encode, like your `Day` object, also need to implement `init(coder:)` and `encode(coder:)`.

In order to conform to NSCoding, your objects need to be `NSObject`s. I'm guessing that your `Day` object does not conform to `NSCoding`.

Comment: Yes it did solve the issue. But can anyone tell me what is the purpose of the required init(coder:)? I did not know what to pass so i just override with another init() and it still works...